# Removing up button from Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've tried looking everywhere but I can't seem to find an answer to how to easily disable the "up button" on the left of the action bar.

I haven't specified a parent activity in my manifest, so I have no idea why it's showing up.

activity in manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ProjectListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_projects"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
 </activity>
```

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure? The up button is disabled by default as far as i know. A must `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` call must be somewhere in your code.

Comment: I just did a search for that in my activity, I don't have it anywhere

Comment: Are you extending `android.app.Activity` or you are using another parent class?

Comment: I'm extending ListActivity

Comment: @Allen can you post an image on what it looks like.

Comment: Good idea @Rod_Algonquin. For reference, [this](http://developer.android.com/images/training/implementing-navigation-up.png) little left-facing caret is created by `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin screenshot added

Comment: @Allen post your ProjectListActivity class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and if i want disable the Logo too, use this:

```
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
```